# How to create a table with columns based on attributes of input XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, dynamic

I have the following 'problem'.
Currently I have this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows language="en">
  <object id="603342" selected="false" urlopen="_open(this, 603342)">
    <RequestType label="Request Type">Support Request</RequestType>
    <Description label="Description">KB 3</Description>
    <Title label="Title">KB 3</Title>
</object>
  <object id="602863" selected="false" urlopen="_open(this, 602863)">
    <RequestType label="Request Type">Known Error</RequestType>
    <Description label="Description">KE 1</Description>
    <Title label="Title">KE 1</Title>
</object>
  <object id="602873" selected="false" urlopen="_open(this, 602873)">
    <RequestType label="Request Type">Known Error</RequestType>
    <Description label="Description">KE 2</Description>
    <Title label="Title">KE 2</Title>
</object>
  <object id="602862" selected="false" urlopen="_open(this, 602862)">
    <RequestType label="Request Type">Standard solution</RequestType>
    <Description label="Description">SS 1</Description>
    <Title label="Title">SS 1</Title>
</object>
  <object id="602871" selected="false" urlopen="_open(this, 602871)">
    <RequestType label="Request Type">Standard solution</RequestType>
    <Description label="Description">SS 2</Description>
    <Title label="Title">SS 2</Title>
</object>
</rows>
```

What I would like is that it would COUNT how many attributes there are in objects as an array.
My XSLT is looking like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="*"> 
      <html>
      <body>
      <h2>Dynamic Table</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="*/*[count(preceding::*) = 0]/@label"/></th>
            <th style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="*/*[count(preceding::*) = 1]/@label"/></th>
            <th style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="*/*[count(preceding::*) = 2]/@label"/></th>

    <xsl:if test="*/*[count(preceding::*) = 3]/@label ='' ">
            <th style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="*/*[count(preceding::*) = 3]/@label"/></th>
    </xsl:if>
    ...............ETC
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="object">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="*[count(preceding-sibling::*) = 0]"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="*[count(preceding-sibling::*) = 1]"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="*[count(preceding-sibling::*) = 2]"/></td>
    <xsl:if test="*/*[count(preceding-sibling::*) = 3]/@label ='' ">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="*[count(preceding-sibling::*) = 3]"/></td>
</xsl:if>

    .............ETC

          </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

So if object has 5 attributes... I want to perform 1 line of code 5 times (for every attribute)

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code looks very odd, it looks as if you want to create an HTML result document but I wonder why you do that in a template matching `*` which matches any element and not for your document node (`match="/"`) or your root element (`match="rows"`). As for processing all attributes of `object` elements, that is as easy as `<xsl:template match="object"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/></xsl:template>` and then writing a template for the attributes or different templates for different attributes if needed.

Comment: I indeed want to create a HTML result document, because it's for a generated website.

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: But as Martin is saying, you don't want to create a new table for every single element in the XML document, do you? for every `<rows>`, `<object>`, `<RequestType>`, `<Description>`, and `<Title>`? Since your template contains a `for-each select="object"`, you apparently want your template to match `"/rows"`.

Comment: I get it. He wants a table output, with one column per distinct element child  of all the objects, and one row per object.

Comment: Indeed Sean! For every attribute I want a column and for every object I want a row.

Comment: Please do show the expected output. The descriptions so far are mutually contradictory.

Comment: `Attribute` has a special meaning in xml. To avoid confusion, please say instead child element of object (eg. `RequestType`).

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin I have rolled your edit back. Please don't EVER put **your** assumptions into the OP's question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I posted my assumptions in the comment feed, and the OP confirmed it. This makes them no longer assumptions, but OP confirmed clarification. My edits were formatting tidy-up plus these confirmed clarifications. Read the comment feed before you rush to judgement.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin "*the OP confirmed it.*" No, I don't think so. You said "*one column per distinct element child of all the objects, and one row per object*" and OP said "*Indeed*". That doesn't mean that the input can be so substantially different from what was originally posted. We all make some assumptions, but I strenuously object to your forcing your assumptions on all of us.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I share your concern that the assumptions Sean made were not strongly confirmed. The OP doesn't seem to have really understood what he assented to. On the other hand, Sean took him at his word, a very reasonable thing to do. I don't think we need to bash him over the head about it. Sean, I agree with Michael that the interpretation of the OP's intent is still sufficiently open to question, that editing the Q so much could just really muddy the water.

Answer (score 2):

How about ....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:key name="cols" match="object/*[@label]" use="@label" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
<body>
      <h2>Dynamic Table</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="rows/object/*
              [
               generate-id() =
               generate-id( key('cols', @label)[1])
              ]"  mode="header" />
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="rows/object" />
       </table>
   </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@label]" mode="header">
  <th style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="@label" /></th>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object">
  <tr>
       <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
       <xsl:for-each select="/rows/object/*
              [
               generate-id() =
               generate-id( key('cols', @label)[1])
              ]">
         <xsl:variable name="col" select="@label" />
          <td>
            <xsl:if test="not( $this/*[@label = $col])">
              <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="$this/*[@label = $col]" />
          </td>
       </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces result ...

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Dynamic Table</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Request Type</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Description</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Support Request</td>
        <td>KB 3</td>
        <td>KB 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Known Error</td>
        <td>KE 1</td>
        <td>KE 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Known Error</td>
        <td>KE 2</td>
        <td>KE 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Standard solution</td>
        <td>SS 1</td>
        <td>SS 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Standard solution</td>
        <td>SS 2</td>
        <td>SS 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is another version...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:key name="cols" match="object/*[@label]" use="@label" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
<body>
      <h2>Dynamic Table</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
             <xsl:apply-templates select="rows/object/*
              [
               generate-id() =
               generate-id( key('cols', @label)[1])
              ]"  mode="header" />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rows/object" />
          </tbody>
       </table>
   </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@label]" mode="header">
  <th style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="@label" /></th>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="body">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="@label" /></td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object">
  <tr>
       <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
       <xsl:for-each select="/rows/object/*[@label]
              [
               generate-id() =
               generate-id( key('cols', @label)[1])
              ]">
         <xsl:variable name="col" select="@label" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="($this/*[@label = $col])[1]" mode="body" />
         <xsl:if test="not( $this/*[@label = $col])">
           <td><xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text></td>
         </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is looking very good.
The only problem is that it will create a new column... but without the header...

Comment: @user3393025 : Updated.

Comment: I see I should be using @label instead  of local-name. I will fix up.

Answer (score 2):

If I am guessing correctly, you want to do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/rows">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <xsl:for-each select="object[1]/*/@label">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="object">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="*[@label]">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which in your example would result in:

[image]

Note that this assumes your table is "regular" - i.e. all objects (rows)  have the same columns.